# Maximal Ideals of Matrix Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, modules

Let $D$ be a division algebra. I'm trying to show that all simple $M_n(D)$ modules are isomorphic to $D^n$. I know that $M_n(D)=D^n\oplus D_n \oplus \dots \oplus D^n$ (n terms).

I have that if $S$ is a simple, then $S\cong M_n(D)/M$ for some maximal ideal $M$. I think the logic goes that $M$ has to be $D^n\oplus D_n \oplus \dots \oplus D^n$ (with $n-1$ terms), and for some reason $M_n(D)/M\cong D^n$.

I'm not sure if this is correct, but if it is, I still don't understand why a maximal ideal of a matrix ring has to be $D^n\oplus D^n \oplus \dots \oplus D^n$ (with $n-1$ terms), or why the quotient would be $D^n$. Thanks for any replies!

Comment: i meant $D^n$, mb

Answer (score 0):

Lemma 1: Show that $D^n$ is a simple right $M_n(D)$ module where you just multiply row vectors from $D^n$ on the right by matrices.

Lemma 2: If $R$ has a simple right ideal $S$, the sum of all right ideals isomorphic to $S$ is atwo-sided ideal of $R$. If two such ideals arise from two collections of nonisomorphic simple right ideals, then the two ideals have intersection zero. Consequently, a simple ring has exactly one isotype of simple right module.

Corollary: all simple right $R$ modules of a simple ring are mutually isomorphic, and so in particular for a matrix ring over a division ring, all simple right modules are isomorphic to $D^n$ with matrix multiplication on the right.

Comment: Ok thanks! I understand the chain of logic completely, but how would I show that the first two sentences of Lemma 2 are true?

Comment: @JamesMachin It's fairly straightforward... did you try to prove them? Such a sum is obviously a right ideal, so the only thing left to do is to show it's a left ideal. Proving the intersection of two different ones is zero is also pretty straightforward.

Comment: Ok so for the first sentence are you talking about the direct sum? So we have to show that if $G\cong H$ are simple right submodules of $M$, then for all pairs (g,h), (g,h)m=(g',h')? I don't understand how this uses the simple property?

Comment: @JamesMachin No, the sum of *all* simple right ideals is not generally direct. It has nothing to do with directness anyway. Do you know what the definition of the sum of right ideals is?

Comment: If it's not the direct product then no I don't!

Comment: @JamesMachin If $M$ has submodules $M_i$, then the sum of these modules $\sum M_i:=\{\sum m_i\mid m_i\in M_i,\text{ only finitely many addends are nonzero. }\}$

Comment: To be honest, I still have no idea how we can switch between ideals and modules; I get that submodules of the M module M are ideals, but have that $M$ is an $R$ module here. Also how can we talk about something being a left ideal when we're talking about right modules? I think I've proved that it's a right submodule though

Comment: @JamesMachin I see what you're saying, but you don't need to be concerned about that :) The definition of "sum" is the same no matter if you're talking about subgroups of an abelian group, subbimodules of a bimodule (like in the case of ideals of a ring) and so on. I'm just saying that the direct sum of mutually isomorphic simple right ideals is certainly a right ideal, and then the set *also* happens to absorb left multiplication too, even though the right ideals may not.

Comment: Well I must admit I'm completely lost. Do you think the way I was going about it in my original post was any good?

Comment: @JamesMachin It's true that each simple right module is isomorphic to the quotient by a maximal right ideal, but it's not very clear how that helps you prove the quotient is isomorphic to $D^n$ because you're stuck with the seemingly equally challenging problem of proving the maximal ideal is isomorphic to $(D^n)^{n-1}$. I really think you will find the way I'm recommending a lot simpler. You believe the sum is a right ideal, right? Have you tried showing it absorbs left multiplication?