# Minimum cardinality module for a fixed finite ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, modules, finite-fields

Let $F$ be a finite field and $k$ be a positive integer.
Let $M_k(F)$ denote the ring of $k\times k$ matrices.

$M_k(F)$ is an $M_k(F)$-module with matrix multiplication, and $F^k$ is an $M_k(F)$-module with matrix-vector multiplication.

Are there any non-trivial $M_k(F)$-modules whose cardinality (the cardinality of the Abelian group) is smaller than $|F|^k$?

Comment: There are a couple of related exercises in Robert Ash's *Abstract Algebra: The Basic Graduate Year*, [Chapter 4](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~r-ash/Algebra/Chapter4.pdf), end of Sec. 4.2.  The analysis of a minimum cardinality (cyclic) module is complicated by the noncommutativity of $M_k(F)$.

Comment: Ash extends the analysis of *simple* modules over a noncommutative ring in [Chapter 9](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~r-ash/Algebra/Chapter9.pdf) of that book.

Comment: With all that spade work, I'm able to offer a previous Question, [Maximal Ideals of Matrix Ring](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/798245/maximal-ideals-of-matrix-ring), that solves and extends your problem to matrices over a division ring (not necessarily finite).

Answer (score 2):

The ring $R=M_k(F)$ is simple and artinian. It follows that there exists a unique simple $R$-module $R$ (up to isomorphism) such that every $R$-module $M$ is isomorphic to a direct sum of copies of $S$.

As the module $S=F^k$, with the obvius action of $R$, is simple, it has to be *that* simple module.

As a consequence of this, the answer to your question is: $|F|^k$.

Comment: "Simple $R$-module $R$" should be "simple $R$-module $S$"?